# how do i get the value of a list item on list item tap in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

I need to pass the values `L`, `PN` and `Y` on list tap as parameter to a webservice.

```
$.each(data.files, function(index, value) {
    $("#yieldlist").append('<li><a href="#"><div>' + value.L + '</div><div>' + value.PN + '</div><div>' + value.Y + '</div></div></a></li>');
}); 
$('#yieldlist').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: <ul id="yieldlist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
  </ul> my list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(data.files, function(index, value) {
    $("#yieldlist").append('<li class="list" data-L="'+value.L+'" data-PN="'+value.PN+'" data-Y="'+value.Y+'"><a href="#"><div>' + value.L + '</div><div>' + value.PN + '</div><div>' + value.Y + '</div></div></a></li>');
});
$('#yieldlist').trigger('create'); 

$(document).on("tap", ".list", function(){
    var l = $(this).attr("data-L");
    var pn = $(this).attr("data-PN");
    var y = $(this).attr("data-Y");
   //alert(l+"=="+pn+"=="+y);
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: your_web_service_url,
       data: { L: l, PN: pn, Y:y}
       success: function(response){        

       }
     }).done(function() {

     })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the inner text and use jquery map to manipulate it. There are lot of good examples available at the folowing link.

http://api.jquery.com/map/